# what is the uses of IClientConfig parameter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

when I look at the implementation of `RibbonConfig` in demos around the web, I notice they always use the `IClientConfig` config parameter, but they never actually use it. For example:

```java
@Autowired
IClientConfig ribbonClientConfig;


@Bean
public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) { // This parameter is never used
    return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
}

@Bean
public IPing ribbonPing(IClientConfig config) {
    return new DummyPing();
}
```

Do you guys know what the `IClientConfig` config parameter used for? It wasn't  used within the method itself in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I found a very similar example in Moises Macero's book: Learn Microservices with Spring Boot, A Practical Approach to RESTful... e.g:

```
public class RibbonConfiguration {

@Bean
public IPing ribbonPing(IClientConfig config) {
    return new PingUrl(false, "/health");
}

@Bean
public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
    return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
}}
```

The scope of this configuration is changing the default Ribbon load balancing strategy.While
Moreover in the official documentation I found this:

```
@Configuration
class DefaultRibbonConfig {
   @Bean
   public IRule ribbonRule() {
      return new BestAvailableRule();
   }

  @Bean
  public IPing ribbonPing() {
    return new PingUrl();
}

  @Bean
   public ServerList<Server> ribbonServerList(IClientConfig config) {
    return new RibbonClientDefaultConfigurationTestsConfig.BazServiceList(config);
}

 @Bean
 public ServerListSubsetFilter serverListFilter() {
     ServerListSubsetFilter filter = new ServerListSubsetFilter();
     return filter;
  }
```

}

As you can see, the first two methods are without IClientConfig parameter, here official docs:
[Customizing the Default for All Ribbon Clients](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html#_customizing_the_default_for_all_ribbon_clients)

So I came back to my config file and I removed IClientConfig parmeter and the program still works.
In my opinion IClientConfig is useless in this moment.
But you can refer to IClientConfig author's comment: [IClientConfig](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/blob/master/ribbon-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/client/config/IClientConfig.java)

> *Defines the client configuration used by various APIs to initialize clients or load balancers
>   and for method execution*.